# Linux File System - Folder Removal with Special Charakters

Tags: linux, directory, remove

we have an Linux Debian Server in our House as Developer Machine.
One of our developers has created accidental an Folder Called `Ð?Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ? Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°`

How can I Remove this folder.

I have tried Several things such as Wildcard, Delete via inode Number, Remove via find, but nothing works.

All i get is

> No such file or Directory

Here is my Complete Screen from my Removal Tests

```
root@debian:/etc# cd /var/mmstylo
root@debian:/var/mmstylo# ls -la
total 13
drwxrwxrwx 6 www-data www-data  296 Apr 11 18:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data   64 Apr 10 13:24 Ð?Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ? Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 4096 Apr 10 13:24 ._.DS_Store
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     6148 Apr 11 18:04 .DS_Store
drwx------ 2 root     root       64 Mar 11 10:31 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x 8 www-data www-data  344 Apr 11 17:21 testwebdav
drwxr-xr-x 8 www-data www-data  280 Apr 10 13:27 webdav
root@debian:/var/mmstylo# rm Ð?Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ? Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°
rm: cannot remove 'Ð?Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ?': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°': No such file or directory
root@debian:/var/mmstylo# rm "Ð?Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ? Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°"
rm: cannot remove 'Ð?Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ? Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°': No such file or directory
root@debian:/var/mmstylo# mc

root@debian:/var/mmstylo# rm -rf "/var/mmstylo/Ð.Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ. Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°"

root@debian:/var/mmstylo# ls -li
total 2
93906511492624 drwxrwxrwx 2 root     root      64 Apr 10 13:24 Ð?Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ? Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°
93906511480544 drwx------ 2 root     root      64 Mar 11 10:31 lost+found
93906511486864 drwxr-xr-x 8 www-data www-data 344 Apr 11 17:21 testwebdav
93906511487328 drwxr-xr-x 8 www-data www-data 280 Apr 10 13:27 webdav
root@debian:/var/mmstylo# find . -inum 93906511492624 -delete
find: cannot delete ‘./Ð\302\235Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ\302\217 Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°’: No such file or directory
root@debian:/var/mmstylo# find . -inum 93906511492624 -exec rm -i {} \;
rm: cannot remove './Ð'$'\302\235''Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ'$'\302\217'' Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°': Is a directory
root@debian:/var/mmstylo# rm *?Ð¾Ð*
rm: cannot remove 'Ð'$'\302\235''Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ'$'\302\217'' Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°': Is a directory
root@debian:/var/mmstylo# find . -inum 93906511492624 -exec rm -ir {} \;
rm: remove directory './Ð'$'\302\235''Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ'$'\302\217'' Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°'? yes
rm: cannot remove './Ð'$'\302\235''Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ'$'\302\217'' Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°': No such file or directory
root@debian:/var/mmstylo# mc

root@debian:/var/mmstylo# rm *Ñ. Ð*
rm: cannot remove '*Ñ.': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'Ð'$'\302\235''Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ'$'\302\217'' Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°': Is a directory

root@debian:/var/mmstylo# rm "*Ñ. Ð*"
rm: cannot remove '*Ñ. Ð*': No such file or directory
root@debian:/var/mmstylo# rm './Ð'$'\302\235''Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ'$'\302\217'' Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°'
rm: cannot remove './Ð'$'\302\235''Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ'$'\302\217'' Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°': Is a directory
root@debian:/var/mmstylo# mv /var/mmstylo/'./Ð'$'\302\235''Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ'$'\302\217'' Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°' /var/mmsytlo/testfolder                                                                                                                    mv: cannot move '/var/mmstylo/./Ð'$'\302\235''Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ'$'\302\217'' Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°' to '/var/mmsytlo/testfolder': No suc                                                                                                                    h file or directory
root@debian:/var/mmstylo# mv './Ð'$'\302\235''Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ'$'\302\217'' Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°' /var/mmstylo/testfolder
mv: cannot move './Ð'$'\302\235''Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ'$'\302\217'' Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°' to '/var/mmstylo/testfolder': Input/output error
root@debian:/var/mmstylo# mc

root@debian:/var/mmstylo# ls *Ñ? Ð*
ls: cannot access '*Ñ?': No such file or directory
Ð?Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ? Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°:
root@debian:/var/mmstylo# rm -r 'Ð?Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ?'' Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°'
rm: cannot remove 'Ð?Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ? Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°': No such file or directory
root@debian:/var/mmstylo# rm -r 'Ð?Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ?''Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°'
rm: cannot remove 'Ð?Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ?Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°': No such file or directory
root@debian:/var/mmstylo# rm -r 'Ð?Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ?' 'Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°'
rm: cannot remove 'Ð?Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ?': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°': No such file or directory
root@debian:/var/mmstylo# rm -r 'Ð?Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ?'*'Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°'
rm: cannot remove 'Ð?Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ?*Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°': No such file or directory
root@debian:/var/mmstylo# rm -r 'Ð?Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ?*Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°'
rm: cannot remove 'Ð?Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ?*Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°': No such file or directory
root@debian:/var/mmstylo# ls -la
total 13
drwxrwxrwx 6 www-data www-data  296 Apr 11 18:04 .
drwxrwxrwx 2 root     root       64 Apr 10 13:24 Ð?Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ? Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 4096 Apr 10 13:24 ._.DS_Store
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     6148 Apr 11 18:04 .DS_Store
drwx------ 2 root     root       64 Mar 11 10:31 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x 8 www-data www-data  344 Apr 11 17:21 testwebdav
drwxr-xr-x 8 www-data www-data  280 Apr 10 13:27 webdav
root@debian:/var/mmstylo# find . -xdev -inum 93906511492624 -exec rm -i '{}' ';'
rm: cannot remove './Ð'$'\302\235''Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ'$'\302\217'' Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°': Is a directory
root@debian:/var/mmstylo#
```

We have to delete this Folder because some of our External Customers gets Virus Errors and Warnings every time about this Folder.

But its empty, and guaranteed no Virus.

Comment: You got several times `is a directory` .. meaning the directory was found. It was just not removed because you forgot the `-r` parameter. Try `rm -r Ð*` again.

Comment: root@debian:/var/mmstylo# rm -r Ð*
rm: cannot remove 'Ð'$'\302\235''Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ'$'\302\217'' Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°': No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

You already have a couple of instances where the directory name is properly escaped and passed correctly to the `rm` command but those result in an error message, for instance:

> rm: cannot remove `'./Ð'$'\302\235''Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ'$'\302\217'' Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°'`: **Is a directory**

The `rm` command without any arguments won't remove directories. Try `rmdir` or use  the `-r` argument for `rm`

Comment: Thanks a Lot, but didn`t work. There is no such file or directory.

Comment: root@debian:/var/mmstylo# rmdir './Ð'$'\302\235''Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ'$'\302\217'' Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°'
rmdir: failed to remove './Ð'$'\302\235''Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ'$'\302\217'' Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°': No such file or directory

Comment: And did `find . -inum 93906511492624 -exec rm -ri {} \;` work better?

Comment: root@debian:/var/mmstylo# find . -inum 93906511492624 -exec rm -ri {} \;
rm: remove directory './Ð'$'\302\235''Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ'$'\302\217'' Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°'? yes
rm: cannot remove './Ð'$'\302\235''Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ'$'\302\217'' Ð¿Ð°Ð¿ÐºÐ°': No such file or directory